# Nested form sends :id instead of friendly_id in POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :courses, path: '' do
  resources :students do
    resources :awards
  end
end
```

**students/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@course, @student, @award] do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ticket %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ticket %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**models/student.rb**

```
belongs_to :course
has_many :awards, dependent: :destroy

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :uuid, use: [ :slugged, :finders ]
```

**controllers/students_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_course

def show
  @student = @course.students.find_by_uuid! params[:id]
  @award = @student.awards.build
  @awards = @student.awards.load.where.not('id' => nil) # exclude empty row
end

private

  def set_course
    @course = Course.find_by_title!(params[:course_id])
  end

  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:email, :uuid, :grade_point_average, :course_id)
  end
```

**controllers/awards_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_variables

def create
  @award = @student.awards.build award_params
  if @award.save
    redirect_to course_student_path(@course, @student.uuid)
  else
    redirect_to course_student_path(@course, @student.uuid)
  end
end

private

  def set_variables
    @course = Course.find_by_title! params[:course_id]
    @student = @course.students.find_by_uuid! params[:student_id]
  end

  def award_params
    params.require(:award).permit(:ticket, :student_id)
  end
```

Now, I would expect my POST request sent from the form to look like this:

```
POST "/3344-2334/students/hh36-f4t4-545t/awards"
```

But this is what the server is getting

```
POST "/3344-2334/students/5/awards"
```

From which I receive an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AwardsController#create
```

Because it gets the **:id (5)** instead of the friendly_id **:uuid (hh36-f4t4-545t)**.

Why is the parent (courses) getting a friendly_id **:title** but the child (students) getting the unfriendly **:id**? I am new to Rails and completely lost.

Comment: for students show, when you navigate to a specific student does the url with uuid or id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default returned param for the student model to give you the uuid instead of the id. Try put this in your student model.

```
def to_param
 uuid
end
```

you can also take a look at [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails), it may help you understand how friendlyId works.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Seems as I should implement at more places. New to Rails, it's like a rollercoaster, going from bliss to despair ...

Comment: If all columns called uuid you can put this method in a concern and include it in the model you want instead of repeating it everywhere.

Comment: Used the `to_param` override for an application where I use `uuid` for any front-facing views but use `id` behind-the-scenes for database relationships and it works perfectly so far. One comment: I used `uuid || id` for my method, just in case a `uuid` isn't set on a particular record (always nice to have fallbacks).