# Nested form with a custom param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**The setup**

I have a standard nested model (note the `param: :uid`):

```
  resources :orders, param: :uid do
    resources :items
  end
```

which gives the following routes:

```
  order_items     GET      /orders/:order_uid/items          items#index
                  POST     /orders/:order_uid/items          items#create
  new_order_item  GET      /orders/:order_uid/items/new      items#new
  edit_order_item GET      /orders/:order_uid/items/:id/edit items#edit
  order_item      GET      /orders/:order_uid/items/:id      items#show
                  PATCH    /orders/:order_uid/items/:id      items#update
                  PUT      /orders/:order_uid/items/:id      items#update
                  DELETE   /orders/:order_uid/items/:id      items#destroy
```

Everything is fine.

**The problem**

When I try to make a nested form for an item, I do the following:

```
<%= form_with(model: [item.order, item], local: true) do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

which works perfectly for both `new` and `edit`. Problem is, that the `order.id` is used to identify the order, and not the `order.uid`.

**Workarounds**

One [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911473/nested-form-sends-id-instead-of-friendly-id-in-post-request) is to set

```
def to_param
  uid
end
```

in the order model, but this breaks other parts of the application, because the UID sometimes needs to be hidden.

When I add an url argument (note: 'order_items_url' with 's'):

```
<%= form_with(model: [item.order, item], url: order_items_url(item.order.uid), local: true) do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

it only works for `new` but not for `edit`.

When I try with (note: 'order_item_url' without 's'):

```
<%= form_with(model: [item.order, item], url: order_item_url(item.order.uid, item.id), local: true) do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

it only works for `edit` and not for `new`.

I could also make a separate form `new` `edit`, or pass the url as a argument to the form-partial.

**The question**

But is there a better (rails) way? Can I e.g., for each object (`order` and `item`), specify which variable to use in the url in the form tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like a rails bug, one would imagine rails would use the routes to correctly build the nested routes, but for some reason it does not seem to work?

A simple work-around would be to write something like

```
<% item_url = item.new_record? ? order_items_url(item.order.uid) : order_item_url(item.order.uid, item.id) %>
<%= form_with(model: [item.order, item], url: item_url, ...
```